# Wireshark UDP filtering hex does not work correctly no?

Tags: udp, wireshark

Is there a bug in Wireshark?

Does not filter properly
ip.addr == 10.222.22.77 and udp contains 0a2001112233
Does filter properly
ip.addr == 10.222.22.77 and udp contains 0a20

```
Frame 9594: 74 bytes on wire (592 bits), 74 bytes captured (592 bits) on 
interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: QQ!! (ZZ!!), Dst: BrocadeC_16:d4:00 (XX!!)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 10.222.22.82, Dst: 10.222.22.77
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 6060, Dst Port: 6060
Data (32 bytes)
Data: 0a20011122334455660000000a05000631090000082a0000...
[Length: 32]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
ip.addr == 10.222.22.77 and udp contains 0a:20:01:11:22:33
```

**EDIT**: If you have [`dftest`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dftest.html), you can run `dftest "udp contains 0a20"`, and you'll get:

```
Filter: "udp contains 0a20"

Constants:
00000 PUT_FVALUE        0a:20 <FT_PROTOCOL> -> reg#1

Instructions:
00000 READ_TREE         udp -> reg#0
00001 IF-FALSE-GOTO     3
00002 ANY_CONTAINS      reg#0 contains reg#1
00003 RETURN
```

... then compare it against `dftest "udp contains 0a2001112233"`:

```
Filter: "udp contains 0a2001112233"

Constants:
00000 PUT_FVALUE        30:61:32:30:30:31:31:31:32:32:33:33 <FT_PROTOCOL> -> reg#1

Instructions:
00000 READ_TREE         udp -> reg#0
00001 IF-FALSE-GOTO     3
00002 ANY_CONTAINS      reg#0 contains reg#1
00003 RETURN
```

To quote from the [wireshark-filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html) man page:

*The "`contains`" operator allows a filter to search for a sequence of characters, expressed as a string (quoted or unquoted), or bytes, expressed as a byte array, or for a single character, expressed as a C-style character constant.*

In the former case, Wireshark interprets the data as a byte array, but in the latter case, it interprets the data as an unquoted character string, so by including the colon's between the bytes, you instruct Wireshark to interpret the data as a byte array, which is the intent.

I don't know if this behavior (interpreting 1 or 2 bytes as a byte array, but interpreting any more than 2 as a character string) should be considered a Wireshark bug or not, but perhaps it should be, in which case feel free to file a [Wireshark bug](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/).  Nevertheless, it is the current behavior, so best practice is to always add a colon after each byte if you're searching for bytes so Wireshark behaves as expected.

Comment: That some how works. The length gets limited to the String some how?

Comment: I amended my answer to provide a more detailed explanation.